# Why is there an asyncio.Future error raised by a concurrent.futures.Future?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, concurrent.futures

I have something equivalent to the following code snippet:

```
import asyncio

futures = []
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
for coroutine in coroutines:
    futures.append(asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(coroutine, loop))
for future in futures:
    future.result()
```

That has raised the following error:

```
in main
    future.result()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/futures.py", line 268, in result
    raise InvalidStateError('Result is not ready.')
```

The error is being raised by an `asyncio.Future` but [`asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe` should return a concurrent.futures.Future](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe) (which, if it were not ready, would block rather than raise an error).

Looking at the implementation of asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe, there's a line which makes me think that it's chaining an `asyncio.Future` to a `concurrent.futures.Future`:

```
futures._chain_future(ensure_future(coro, loop=loop), future)
```

Whatever the problem is here, it works the vast majority of the time. This is an attempt to describe a reported bug that has not proved to be reproducible.

Can anyone shed some light on what's going on?

Comment: Can you please provide a runnable minimal example that demonstrates the issue? For example, [this](https://pastebin.com/Qn1zFnVk) works as expected. Perhaps you have a `future` variable left from before that contains an `asyncio.Future`, and whose `result()` you are invoking instead of the future returned from `run_coroutine_threadsafe`?

Comment: Unfortunately not, it's a bug in our code that's been reported to me. We've been unable to reproduce the issue.

Comment: In first snippet you get `loop`, but pass `event_loop` to `run_coroutine_threadsafe`. It's ok?

Comment: Not okay :-) But just a typo from stripping out all of our sensitive code.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since this was asked but I think you get this exception because of this part of the `run_coroutine_threadsafe`:

```
except BaseException as exc:
    if future.set_running_or_notify_cancel():
        future.set_exception(exc)
        raise
```

This essentially takes the exception that happened during the previous step, and attaches it to the `concurrent.futures.Future`. Which means that you can get an asyncio `InvalidStateError` (which inherits from `BaseException`) thrown by the `concurrent.futures.Future`. It does not mean that the Future is an asyncio Future. However it means that your error probably comes from the `ensure_future` part of the code of `run_coroutine_threadsafe`.